# Ramallah, Palestine cannot detect in Google place picker

Tags: android, google-places-api

When I am typing and select **Ramallah** from Place Picker, it shows **West Bank Palestine**.

When I am going to perform Geocoding on Latlong, it just fetches the only country.

**Edit 1:** I already have migrated Place Picker SDK with the help of [Migrating to the New Places SDK Client | Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)
 link

Please let me know any workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is an intended behavior that Geocoding API responses for locations in **[disputed territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes)** to not include results or address components representing countries or any level of administrative areas. Here's a [related post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826813) in Google's Public Issue Tracker.